# convert a vector of values in a cell of a dataframe as a column values for corresponding row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns.

- 1st column has an id
- 2nd column has words

```
    ID   WORDS
    1    c(row1_word1, row1_word2, ...)
    2    c(row2_word1, row2_word2, ...)
```

I would like to have a data.frame as follows

```
ID   word
1    row1_word1
1    row1_word2
.
.
.
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2), 
  words = list(c("one", "two"), c("three", "four", "five"))
)

dat %>% unnest(words)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#      id words
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 one  
# 2     1 two  
# 3     2 three
# 4     2 four 
# 5     2 five
```

Comment: Actually the content of the cell looks like ````c('word1','word2')````. not really list object.

Comment: Can you post the results of `dput(head(dat))` where you replace `dat` with your dataset name so we can be working with the right data?  Alternatively show us how to make the data that has similar properties.

Comment: I updated the table in the content of the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @sveer It still doesn't really work.  I don't know how to make a data frame that looks like that.  If I made just that using `tribble()` from the `tibble` package it would make exactly the tibble that I made in my answer.  It would be helpful to actually post your data or the instructions to make a valid R object that has the required properties.

Comment: Thank you! I am converting the words into an object as a list and try. i will infrom you soon!